# Comparing timespec values

Tags: c++, linux, gnu

What's the best way to compare two timespec values to see which happened first?

Is there anything wrong with the following?

```
bool BThenA(timespec a, timespec b) {
    //Returns true if b happened first -- b will be "lower".
    if (a.tv_sec == b.tv_sec)
        return a.tv_nsec > b.tv_nsec;
    else
        return a.tv_sec > b.tv_sec;
}
```

Comment: This Looks good to me

Answer (score 8):

Another way you can go this is to have a global `operator <()` defined for `timespec`.  Then you can just you that to compare if one time happened before another.

```
bool operator <(const timespec& lhs, const timespec& rhs)
{
    if (lhs.tv_sec == rhs.tv_sec)
        return lhs.tv_nsec < rhs.tv_nsec;
    else
        return lhs.tv_sec < rhs.tv_sec;
}
```

Then in you code you can have

```
timespec start, end;
//get start and end populated
if (start < end)
   cout << "start is smaller";
```

Comment: For this to work he has to decide if this a C or C++ question.  It's currently tagged as both.

Comment: @BrianMcFarland True.  I came in from the C++ side so I didn't see the C tag.

Comment: It could be either depending on circumstances.